# MySQL query which has LIKE and AND clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query:

```
$query="SELECT * FROM products 
                 WHERE  productname LIKE '%$searchterm%' 
                 OR shortdescription LIKE '%$searchterm%' 
                 OR description LIKE  '%$searchterm%' AND VISIBLE != 0";
```

The query returns records that i want, but also returns records which has visible = 0.

Can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong?

Regards,Zoran

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's about [operator precedence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations)

Operator `AND` is running first then `OR`.

So your query is like this:

```
$query="SELECT * FROM products 
                 WHERE  productname LIKE '%$searchterm%' 
                 OR shortdescription LIKE '%$searchterm%' 
                 OR (description LIKE  '%$searchterm%' AND VISIBLE != 0");
```

Fix your query to this:

```
$query="SELECT * FROM products 
                 WHERE  (productname LIKE '%$searchterm%' 
                 OR shortdescription LIKE '%$searchterm%' 
                 OR description LIKE  '%$searchterm%') AND VISIBLE != 0";
```

Answer (score 1):

Use parenthesis:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    products 
WHERE  
    (
        productname LIKE '%$searchterm%' 
     OR shortdescription LIKE '%$searchterm%' 
     OR description LIKE  '%$searchterm%'
    ) 
AND VISIBLE != 0
```